# Sending mail from Docker container

Tags: rhel, docker, postfix, container

I want to send mails from my `docker container` .  We have an `SMTP relay host` in our network which forwards mail traffic to the `SMTP` server .

I manually installed `postfix` in our docker container and configured `relayhost` parameter to point to `SMTP relay host`

But mails are not going through . In fact looking at `maillog` on `SMTP relay server` does not show it is receiving mails from docker container .

How can I make mail working from docker container?

Details below

```
 SMTP relayhost hostname: mail.example.com

 From Docker container

    [root@fe7a16b08ab6 /]# nc -v mail.example.com 25
    Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
    Ncat: Connected to 10.100.4.39:25.
    220 car-lnxsupq-001.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
```

^C

Comment: Your `nc` example with the `220` response shows the docker container can connect (try sending a mail with `nc` or `telnet` for completeness of this check and rule out misconfiguration of the relay host). So it must be an error in the `postfix` configuration.

Comment: It is working from commandline using `telnet` command . On checking further I see postfix not running inside contaoner , so mails are not forwarded to relay mail server.

Comment: I am at the same point. I can connect to host postfix in port 25 and send emails using netcat. But can't configure postfix in the container to use the rely host. Did u found the solution?